# Convert data source from string to Date in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a string format like this example

**60617**

this means date "6 June 2017"
i want to convert my data in column tableau data source but this return "null"

i want it result become data like
**6/06/2017**

is there any other step beside klick the data type in the screen data source?
Thankyou

Comment: try this `MAKEDATE(int('20'+''+right('60617',2)),int(left('60617',1)),int(MID('60617',2,2)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be the best answer but does the job.

Create a calculated field using the Makedate function. The makedate takes the three parts of date as its arguments.

**MAKEDATE(year,month,day).**

```
MAKEDATE(2000+INT(RIGHT(STR([F1]),2)),INT(MID(STR([F1]),2,2)),INT(LEFT(STR([F1]),1)))

     For Year : 2000+INT(RIGHT(STR([F1]),2))
     For Month: INT(MID(STR([F1]),2,2))
     For Day  : INT(LEFT(STR([F1]),1)) 

     **Result : 6/6/2017**
```

Comment: plus 1, nice ! but performance is slow, if used on big table.

Comment: This fails for days with 2 digits.

Comment: Dateparse() is useful here, although you'll need to handle both 6 and 7 character strings separately. Performance won't suffer if you make an extract so only call the function during extract creation